# How to get all descendants of a node with Django treebeard?

Tags: python, django, django-models, descendant, django-treebeard

Let's say I have these Models:

```
class Category(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Item(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

and I would like to find all `Item`s belonging to any [descendant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#Terminologies_used_in_Trees) of a given `Category`.

Usually I would write `category.item_set` but this is just `Item`s belonging to the given level of the hierarchy.

Using the example tree in the [treebeard tutorial](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/docs/2.0/tutorial.html), if an Item belongs to "Laptop Memory", how would I find all Items belonging to descendants "Computer Hardware" where "Laptop Memory" is one of those descendants?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and figured out how to do it (consider it inside the function `get_queryset` of a `ListView`):

```
category = Category.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['category']).get()
descendants = list(category.get_descendants().all())
return self.model.objects.select_related('category').filter(category__in=descendants+[category, ])
```

Another option that I came up with was using a filter with 'OR':

```
from django.db.models import Q

category = Category.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['category']).get()
descendants = list(category.get_descendants().all())
return self.model.objects.select_related('category').filter(Q(category__in=category.get_descendants()) | Q(category=category))
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the treebeard code to see how it gets descendants of a node. We can apply the same filters as a related field lookup.

```
paramcat = Category.objects.get(id=1) # how you actually get the category will depend on your application
#all items associated with this category OR its descendants:
items = Item.objects.filter(category__tree_id=paramcat.tree_id, category__lft__range=(paramcat.lft,paramcat.rgt-1))
```

I think using intermediate calls like get_descendants will result in one query per descendant, plus load all descendants into memory. It defeats the purpose of using treebeard in the first place

I'd be interested in seeing a custom lookup based on this code, I'm not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can get all descendants of a category with [get_descendants()](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_descendants) in `views.py` as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76776167/how-to-get-the-all-descendants-of-a-node-including-itself-with-django-treebeard/76776168#76776168) explaining how to get all descendants of a category including the model instance itself with `get_descendants(include_self=True)`:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Category, Product

def test(request):
    categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants()
    print(categories) 
    # <TreeQuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>

    products = Product.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
    print(products)
    # <QuerySet [<Product: Beef>, <Product: Pork>, <Product: Salmon>

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```