# How to get the all descendants of a node including itself with Django treebeard?

Tags: python, django, django-models, descendant, django-treebeard

I have `Category` model extending [MP_Node](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mp_tree.html) with [Django treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node

class Category(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    node_order_by = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, I could get all descendants of a category not including itself with `get_descendants()` using **Django treebeard** as shown below:

```py
categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants()
print(categories)
# <MP_NodeQuerySet [<Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>
```

But, when I tried to get all descendants of a category including itself with `get_descendants(include_self=True)` using **Django treebeard**, I got the error as shown below:

```py
categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants(include_self=True)
print(categories) # Error
```

> TypeError: get_descendants() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_self'

Actually, I could get all descendants of a category including itself with `get_descendants(include_self=True)` using [Django mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) as shown below. *I switched **Django mptt** to **Django treebeard** because **Django mptt** is unmaintained and gives some error:

```py
categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants(include_self=True)
print(categories)
# <TreeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>
```

So, how can I get the all descendants of a category including itself with **Django treebeard**?

Answer (score 0):

You can override [get_descendants()](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_descendants) and add `include_self=False` to it as the 2nd argument with [Django treebeard](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard) as shown below. *You can see the original [get_descendants()](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard/blob/f9674d0adf2ae3077c4475895f0df074179102c7/treebeard/mp_tree.py#L1025):

```py
from django.db import models
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node, get_result_class

class Category(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    node_order_by = ('name',)

    def get_descendants(self, include_self=False):
        if include_self:
            return self.__class__.get_tree(self)
        if self.is_leaf():
            return get_result_class(self.__class__).objects.none()
        return self.__class__.get_tree(self).exclude(pk=self.pk)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, you can get the all descendants of a category including itself with **Django treebeard** as shown below:

```py
categories = Category.objects.get(name="Food").get_descendants(include_self=True)
print(categories)
# <MP_NodeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>
```

In addition, you can get the all descendants of a category including itself with [get_tree(parent=None)](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_tree) using **Django treebeard** as shown below. *You need to use an object to use `get_tree(parent=None)`:

```py
categories = Category.objects.all()[2].get_tree(Category.objects.get(name="Food"))
print(categories)
# <MP_NodeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>

categories = Category.objects.first().get_tree(Category.objects.get(name="Food"))
print(categories)
# <MP_NodeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>

categories = Category.objects.last().get_tree(Category.objects.get(name="Food"))
print(categories)
# <MP_NodeQuerySet [<Category: Food>, <Category: Meat>, <Category: Fish>]>
```